# ¿Generar una clave única por el usuario en Firebase?

Tags: firebase

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que registra libros en Firebase. El siguiente código realiza
esa tarea y funciona bien.
 //Procedimiento para Grabar o Escribir datos en Firebase:

```
   btn_Agregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String titulo = et_Titulo.getText().toString();
    String autor = et_Autor.getText().toString();
            String isbn = et_Isbn.getText().toString();
            String edicion = et_Edicion.getText().toString();
            String numhojas = et_NHojas.getText().toString();

      if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)||!TextUtils.isEmpty(titulo)||!TextUtils.isEmpty(autor)||!TextUtils.isEmpty(isbn)
               ||!TextUtils.isEmpty(edicion)||!TextUtils.isEmpty(numhojas)){


                Libro z = new Libro( titulo, autor, isbn, edicion, numhojas );
                String item = db.push().getKey();
                db.child(item).setValue(z);


Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Libro agregado" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Pero lo que no logro hacer y les pido ayuda. Es generar, en vez de la clave única KgtvuDfQeRRLYoN2MI.

Una clave generada por el usuario: Libro 001, por cada libro que se ingrese, vaya sumando o agregando, según corresponda. Segundo libro ingresado .... Libro 002, tercer libro ingresado .... Libro 003.
 La idea es ir ingresando libros con un número correlativo y secuencial.
 En lugar de esas letras ilegibles (claves únicas).

Alguien me dirá que genere otro nodo con su clave-valor. De esta manera, clave "Libro" y un valor "00NN.." y así, para cada libro que se ingrese.
  Si. Eso ya se pensó. 
 Pero la aplicación esta diseñada para que una persona ingrese los libros y llevar un control.  [image: Adjunto una imagen de referencia.]La aplicación se visualizará en monitor, además de teléfono. Al desplegar la información en monitores, las claves únicas, van
 a "ensuciar" mucho el despliegue de los datos, en pantalla.

```
       Desde ya gracias.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo unico que deberias cambiar es esta linea

```
String item = db.push().getKey();
```

`push()` lo que hace es crear una clave alfanumerica random y asi evitar que las referencias se pisen si se crean iguales.

para solucionarlo solo deberias hacer algun contador que vaya sumando los libros que el usuario va ingresando y cambiar

```
String item = db.push().getKey();
```

por

```
String item = db.child("Libro 001");
```

pero en vez de hacer eso deberias poner dentro de ese child un valor que no se repita por usuario, por que si otro usuario crea el mismo child podria pisar el de otro usuario

para eso yo haria lo siguiente

Crearia dentro de cada usuario (si es que tienes un login) los libros, entonces cada usuario tiene sus libros y no estan todos los libros que se crean en un mismo lugar

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


Sting item = db.child(uid).child("Libro 001 y los demas...");
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Genial  Gastón !!!..... funciona!!!   a continuación detallo el código.

Comment: Libro z = new Libro( id, titulo, autor, isbn, edicion, numhojas );
                String item = db.child(id).getKey();
                db.child(item).setValue(z);

Comment: genial, si te sirvio no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta , de esa manera mas gente con el mismo problema puede que le sirva

Comment: Agregue un EditText que lo denomine id.  En este el usuario escribirá el "Libro 001" ....funciona perfectamente   Muchas, muchas gracias Gastón. Esto le servirá a muchos.

Comment: excelente, asi es

Comment: Dónde se debe marcar para dar la respuesta como la correcta...?????  Ya h lo hice, gracias.

Comment: al lado de mi respuesta hay un tilde y una flechita , puedes apretar el tilde para aceptar la respuesta y la flechita hacia arriba para darme un punto si deseas :)

Comment: me aparece que no lo marcaste, saludos, fijate que tiene que aparecer el tilde al lado de mi pregunta , lo apretas y se pone en verde, me ayuda mucho a seguir respondiendo

Comment: Acabo de marcar la flecha hacia arriba. Pero se mantiene en gris. Saludos  Gastón.

Comment: Es el visto bueno el que debo marcar. Hecho está.